# How to recover admin password web2py

Tags: administrator, ubuntu-server, password-recovery

I have a web2py instance that is deployed, but I can't figure out what the admin password was. Is there a way to recover the admin password in web2py?

I tried to remove parameters.py file, but now it says that admin is disabled.

```
sudo rm parameters_8000.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite parameters.py file like so:

```
sudo -u www-data python -c "from gluon.main import save_password; save_password('123456', 8000)"
```

You need to be in web2py folder in order for this command to work properly.

You should replace '123456' with a better/secure password.

Comment: Asking questions and answering them with another account is considered abusive. The Gus account can answer his own question though.